# Check array of values are exist in the database MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a database table `"Mytable"` which contains 2 columns (`"colimn1"` and `"column2"`). I also have a list of values of `column1` where I need to cross check with the table to verify the values are exist in the table or not. All the non-existing values in the list should be displayed as a result of the query.

E.g.

```
Value list = ["c1","c2", "c3", "c4"]
Values in the database = C2 and C3
```

Therefore the result should be c1 and c4 after cross-checking with the database.

I have tried with if condition, but then I have to write seperate queries for every row

```
select if(exists(select column2_val from myTable where column2_val = '3c2'), 'display when true', 'display when false');
```

Here I am providing a long list of column2 values and What I want is to display all the values which are not there in the table as the final result?

Comment: MySQL has no datatype called "list", so it is unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: I have updated the question. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a temporary table and insert whatever the list and then have to write a query considering the 2 tables to find the non-existing once.

Although the temporary tables will be destroyed once your session is over, you still need to make sure that the tempory table values are not taking much memory which affects your performance

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this would work better if you had those values to check in a table.  Then, you could easily use a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.column2_val
FROM
(
    SELECT 'c1' AS column2_val UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c4'
) t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable t2 WHERE t1.column2_val = t2.column2_val);
```

Comment: Here I am providing a long list of column2 values and What I want is to display all the values which are not there in the table as the final result

Comment: See Gordon's comment above.  SQL works with _tables_, not lists.